# Usando jsPDF y html2canvas genera hojas en blanco y contenido grande

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

estoy usando una libreria de jsPDF y html2canvas para convertir en PDF algo que tengo en un div

este es mi div

```
<div id="zima">
                <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless mb-0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="w-50">
                    <div class="bg-custom bg-opacity-100 text-white fw-semibold text-center" style="background-color: rgba(13,110,253, var(--bs-bg-opacity));">MAKE CHECKS PAYABLE TO</div>
                    <div class="text-center mb-3 p-2"><img id="brandInvoice" class="brandInvoice w-50" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
                    <p id="addressInvoice" class="addressInvoice m-0">23961 Calle de la Magdalena ste 300</p>
                    <span id="cityInvoice" class="cityInvoice">Laguna Hills</span>&nbsp;<span class="stateInvoice" id="stateInvoice">CA</span>&nbsp;<span class="zipcodeInvoice" id="zipcodeInvoice">74455</span>
                    <p id="nitInvoice" class="nitInvoice mb-3">1234567890</p>
                    <p id="phoneInvoice" class="phoneInvoice m-0 fw-bold">949900530</p>
                    <p id="emailInvoice" class="emailInvoice mb-2 fw-bold">billing@healthit.me</p>
                    <div id="barcodeInvoice" class="barcodeInvoice">
                        <h6 class="barcodeInvoice"><b>||| || |||||| ||| | ||||| || |||| |||||||| || |||||| ||| | ||||| || |||| ||</b></h6>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="w-50">
                    <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" class="text-center p-0"><small class="very-small fw-semibold">IF PAYING BY MASTERCARD, DISCOVER, VISA OR AMEX, FILL OUT BELOW.</small></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" class="text-center pt-0">
                                    <small class="very-small fw-semibold">CHECK CARD USING FOR PAYMENT</small>
                                    <table class="table table-borderless table-sm mb-0">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td class="p-0"><img class="me-1" style="width: 40px;" src="../img/payment/mastercard.png"><div style="width: 12px;height: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" class="d-inline-block p-1 border border-dark"></div></td>
                                            <td class="p-0"><img class="me-1" style="width: 40px;" src="../img/payment/discover.png"><div style="width: 12px;height: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" class="d-inline-block p-1 border border-dark"></div></td>
                                            <td class="p-0"><img class="me-1" style="width: 40px;" src="../img/payment/visa.png"><div style="width: 12px;height: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" class="d-inline-block p-1 border border-dark"></div></td>
                                            <td class="p-0"><img class="me-1" style="width: 40px;" src="../img/payment/amex.png"><div style="width: 12px;height: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" class="d-inline-block p-1 border border-dark"></div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="pt-1"><small class="very-small fw-semibold align-top">CARD NUMBER</small></td>
                                <td class="pt-1"><small class="very-small fw-semibold align-top">EXP. DATE</small></td>
                                <td class="pt-1"><small class="very-small fw-semibold align-top">*ID CODE</small></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="pt-1"><small class="very-small fw-semibold align-top">NAME ON CARD</small></td>
                                <td class="pt-1"><small class="very-small fw-semibold align-top">SIGNATURE</small></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><small>STATEMENT DATE</small><br><b class="dateInvoice">4/1/2023</b></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><small>TOTAL TO PAY</small><br><b>$<span class="totalInvoice">1000</span></b></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><small>ACCOUNT NUMBER</small><br><b>108573</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-borderless mb-0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="very-small fw-semibold">*LAST THREE DIGITS ON BLACK OF CREDIT CARD</td>
                                <td class="fw-semibold border border-top-0 pt-1"><small>SHOW TO BE PAID HERE</small><br><b>$<span class="totalInvoice">1000</span></b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-borderless">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-borderless">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="w-50 p-1"><div class="bg-custom bg-opacity-100 text-white fw-semibold text-center" style="background-color: rgba(13,110,253, var(--bs-bg-opacity));">ADDRES SEE</div></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="namePatientInvoice px-1 p-0">Jhon  Cordoba </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="addressPatientInvoice px-1 py-0">Carrera 20 sur 9-50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="px-1 py-0"><span class="cityPatientInvoice"></span>&nbsp;<span class="statePatientInvoice">Valle del Cauca</span>&nbsp;<span class="zipcodePatientInvoice">76000</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="phonePatientInvoice px-1 p-0">3156893089</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="cntLaboratory" style="display: none;">
                    <table class="table table-borderless">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="w-50 p-1"><div class="bg-custom bg-opacity-100 text-white fw-semibold text-center" style="background-color: rgba(13,110,253, var(--bs-bg-opacity));">PLEASE SENDER TO</div></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="nameLabInvoice" class="nameLabInvoice px-1 p-0">HARVARD EYE ASSOCIATES</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="addressLabInvoice" class="addressLabInvoice px-1 py-0">181 W. OLYMPIC BLVD</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="px-1 py-0"><span id="cityLabInvoice" class="cityLabInvoice">PASADENA</span><span id="stateLabInvoice" class="stateLabInvoice">CA</span><span id="zipcodeLabInvoice" class="zipcodeLabInvoice">91199</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="phoneLabInvoice px-1 p-0">900503015</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
<div class="mb-2">
    <div style="width: 12px;height: 12px; vertical-align: middle;" class="d-inline-block ms-1 p-1 border border-dark"></div>
    <span class="very-small fw-semibold">Please check box if address is incorrect or insurance. Information has changed, and indicate change(s) on reverse side.</span>
</div>
<hr class="position-relative cut" style="border-style: dashed">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-sm table-borderless mb-0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><small class="very-small fw-semibold">PLEASE DETACH AND RETURN TOP PORTIOIN WITH YOUR PAYMENT</small></td>
                <td class="text-center"><h6><b>INVOICE</b></h6></td>
                <td class="text-end"><small class="very-small fw-semibold">* IDENTIFICATION CODE LAST THESE DIGITS ON BACK OF MC, DISCOVER, AND VISA</small></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive bg-custom bg-opacity-10" style="background-color: rgba(13,110,253, var(--bs-bg-opacity));">
    <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>Description of services</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Patient</th>
                <th>Charge</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodyInvoice"><tr><td align="center">Odontology appointment</td><td align="center">2023-01-18</td><td align="center">Jhon Cordoba</td><td align="center">$1000</td></tr></tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
<p class="text-center mb-0"><small class="websiteInvoice fw-bold">Healthit.com</small></p>
<div id="footerInvoice" class="footerInvoice text-center">
    <small><b>You can now pay your bill online! Simply go to healthit.me, select Patients / Make a payment.</b></small>
</div>          </div>
```

este es mi boton

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="pdfsave()"> Save PDF</button>
```

y este es mi js

```
<script>
function pdfsave(){
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
    var margin = 10;
    var scale = (doc.internal.pageSize.width - margin * 2) / document.getElementById('zima').scrollWidth;
    doc.html(document.getElementById('zima'),{
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale,
        },
        callback: function(doc){
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow',{finelane: 'ensayo.pdf'});
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

me esta generando el PDF de maravilla, pero muy grande el contenido y me esta generando unas hojas de mas, no se si alguien tenga conocimiento con estas librerias ya que es la primera vez que la utilizo, muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si me gustaria que el contenido fuera mas pequeño, he movido la propiedad scale y me sale todo en blanco, inclusive eliminandolo y nada, investigue que la escala tiene que ver con el tamaño del dispositivo pero nada, ya no se que hacer

agradeceria de ante mano su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya solucione mi problema, ya resolvi mis problemas, cacharreando de todo un poco, influye el tamaño del div o html que vas a capturar, si el div esta con un width del 50%, eso influye, y las hojas en blancos es debido a que internamente no se como se comporte la libreria html2canvas, pero no acepta bootstrap, me toco eliminar los class que pertenecen a los bootstrap y hacerlo html puro sin bootstrap para que no me salieran hojas en blanco

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como correcta. También proporciona el código de lo que has hecho (en texto, no imagen) para que comiences  a ganar reputación y medallas.